# Конвектор в pdf: проблема с кодировкой

Tags: pdf, кодировка, javascript

[Вот сделал такую штуку](http://jsfiddle.net/y2b7Q/2552/), всё работает, всё хорошо, но проблема в том, что если в инпут вбить русские символы, открывается в пдф абракадабра вместо русских символов, подскажите, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, вам поможет [такое](https://toster.ru/q/52020) решение.

Comment: @Yaroslav Senko, к сожалению, не смогу попробовать, подключил tcpdf (он на php), с ним как-то проще оказалось.